# Background color in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a background color and I need to add another color in the middle. This one for example *([https://yifymovie.re)](https://yifymovie.re)_)* in the middle is white. Another question how can I make the bar in the middle.

Thanks.

```css
.BarSize {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 360px;
  width: 1200px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 9px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yifymovie.re/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">

<div class="BarSize">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: you mean line between links?

Comment: explain more about this

Comment: In the middle is white because there is some _element_ (e.g. div) that is white, not white background.

Comment: that what i want i need another color in the middle how ?

Comment: You use `position: absolute` with offsets in `px`. This will not work for different screen sizes (mobile, tablet, laptop). I would redo all the layout with different screen sizes in mind.

Comment: can you give me the whole command ? like how to type it because im new :and thanks for help .

Answer (score 0):

Here I style `body` as a [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) container (here is a [game for learning flex](http://flexboxfroggy.com/)) to center its children. In old browsers without `flex` you could use [`margin: 0 auto`](http://learnlayout.com/margin-auto.html).

Inside `main-sheet` there is a `div` with white background.

Notice that I don't use fixed offsets in `px` so this page will work for all screen-sizes.

https://jsfiddle.net/03p2ysvL/2/

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-sheet {
  min-width: 80%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 9px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>abc</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main-sheet">

  <div class="BarSize">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: white">
    I have white background!
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much (:

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` is [suggested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Horizontal_centering_with_margin_0_auto) to be replaced with `flex` in modern browsers, so I changed my answer. Don't forget to mark one solution as a correct answer and upvote solutions you've found useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @ilyaigpetrov already said in the comments, you need to put some element there.

The most common way to do this is to put a new element there that contains everything else (here `<div id="page">`). Then there is your navigation bar (`<div class="BarSize">`), and then a new div for the actual content (`<div class="content">`).

And then in CSS, we need to set the `max-width` property for the `#page`. Otherwise the whole thing would cover the whole screen, and you wouldn't get the black areas on the sides.

Also we need to set the `background-color` of `.content` to white, and the `background-color` of `body` to grey or black.

So here is what you want to do:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey; /* This is the color in the sides */
}

#page {
  max-width: 500px; /* This is how wide you want everything to be */
  margin: 0 auto; /* And this trick centers everything horizontally */
}

.BarSize { /* this is only a placeholder, replace with you actual navbar code */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
} /* placeholder ends */

.content {
  background-color: white; /* This is the color in the middle */
  
  padding: 2em; /* This is again only an example, doesn't affect the layout */
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="BarSize">
    <!-- This is your navigation bar, replace with your code -->
  </div>
    
  <div class="content">
    Here you can put your content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change the color adding the styling to .wrapper class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.BarSize {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 360px;
  width: 1200px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 9px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yifymovie.re/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">

<div class="BarSize">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```